# Add column to Pandas DataFrame based on formula

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dictionary with JSON values keyed to the value of a column (`name`) in my data frame, and I want to add some columns to the data frame drawn from the dictionary.

I've tried to do this with something like:

```
df['district_name'] = data[df['name']]['district_name']
```

but that doesn't work at all (it gives a "Series aren't valid keys", which makes perfect sense; I've never quite understood the black magic that allows `df['col3'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']` to work). Other answers here have led me to try something like:

```
df['district_name'] = df.apply(lambda row:data[row['name']]['district_name'])
```

This gives me `KeyError: ('name', 'occurred at index Name')`.

How can I best accomplish this?

Comment: can you provide some test data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close. Try this:

```
df['district_name'] = df['name'].map(data.get)['district_name']
```